# I lost my game how could I return my account

Tags: clash-of-clans

[image]townhall 8 level 8 base Max diffence troops I did not have any clan my base name is pran etc

Comment: Please don't use random games to tag your question. Game-specific tags exist for a reason.

Answer (score -1):

You can try contacting Supercell support, with all of these details, then try to sign up for Supercell ID to prevent this from occurring again. I have never used any of their products, but their layout looks like it is the same as many others. I do not know how their game structures save data, so they may or may not still have it. Be sure to group up as much info you can about your account, and when you last used it to support that it is yours.